Order of certain points of elliptic curves over $\overline {\mathbb{F}_{p}}$
Let $p\neq 2$ be a prime number, $E$ an elliptic curve over $\overline {\mathbb{F}_{p}}$ defined by the equation $y^{2}=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$, and $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ the double covering that is ramified over $0, 1, \infty, \lambda$.
We know that $f^{-1}(\lambda)\in E(\overline {\mathbb{F}_{p}})$ are $2$-torsion points of $E$.
Can we know some information about the orders of $f^{-1}(\pm\lambda^{n})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$? For example, is the order of any element of $f^{-1}(\pm\lambda^{n})$ prime to $p$ if $E$ is ordinary?

Euler proved for the cases p = 2 and p = 3 that the equation you wrote is divisible by p if and only if it is a square modulo p

try this, which primes are like (x^2 - 1)(y^ - 1) with rational values of x and y

Fix $p$ and $n$ and let $m$ be an integer. If you ask that $f^{-1}(\lambda^n)$ has order $m$, you get a polynomial in $\lambda$. So there are only finitely many $\lambda$ such that the degree of $f^{-1}(\lambda^n)$ is less than any given constant. But you can also easily find points whose order is divisible by $p$ and where $E$ is ordinary (there are only finitely many supersingular $E$). In the very first case with $p=3$ and $n=2$, you find that
if $\lambda^3 - \lambda + 1 = 0$ that $P=[\lambda^2,\lambda+1]$ has order $3$ and $E$ is ordinary. So the answer to Q2 is no. (Q1 is just too vague)

OTOH there are no examples to Q2 if $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}p$ since then $f^{-1}(\lambda^n)$ always lies in $E(\mathbf{F}{p^2})$ but any $E/\mathbf{F}_p$ with a $2$-torsion can't have a point of order $p>3$ over $\mathbf{F}p$ or $\mathbf{F}{p^2}$ since by the Weil conjectures this would force $a_p(E) = \pm 1$.
